# Selenium After sendkey, do some validation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm new to Selenium, TestNG and Stackoverflow.

After sendkeys, I want to do some validation. If the validation is true, then the assert is true. I know this is not the right way to write the Assert method.

```html
    WebDriver driver;

    @DataProvider(name= "testdata")
    public static Object[][] loginData(){

        return new Object[][]{{"username1", "123"}, {"username2", "4211"}};
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void configure(){
      ....
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "testdata")
    public void testmethod(String uname, String password){

         WebElement usernameTextbox = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
       usernameTextbox.sendKeys(uname);

   WebElement passwordTextbox = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
       passwordTextbox.sendKeys(uname);
         
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
         
Assert.assertTrue(if(usernameTextbox.contains("[a-zA-Z0-9]+") &&  passwordTextbox.contains("[0-9]+") == true));
```

PS: Any inputs will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: in sendKeys you are sending username and password that you already  know , why do you need to test this feature ? any usecase ?

Comment: @cruisepandey I tried to print the value of the textbox. It return me nulll.

Comment: It's obvious that It'd return null cause , you have just given the values , and you want to retrieve those values but the  DOM has not updated yet

Comment: @cruisepandey so there is no way to retrieve those values? or is it possible.

Comment: You already have those value , present in @DataProvide method. Can you please elaborate your use case ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Based on a group of valid and invalid inputs, the use case is to check if the given value is in the right format. Instead of doing client-side form validation, I'm using selenium to do it.

Comment: Unti you submit your form those value are not going to retiver from DOM

Comment: @AnkurSingh Do you mean by .... Although after include" driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();" and put the validation after it , the DOM is not updated? And thus, I am not be able to retrieve the inputs?

Comment: @AnkurSingh : how will you access server side values once the user have clicked on submit button using selenium?

Comment: Yes until your not goan submit. Dom will not reflect those change..You can try Search... Box of stack overflow if you enter some thing then check DOM you ll not find any thing .. but after click on search icon you can see change in DOM then you inspect element you ll find your search value in DOM

Comment: @AnkurSingh : searching somethings and credentials differs when it comes to security. No website will update their DOM regarding credentials although DOM would be updated

Comment: @cruisepandey Since the DOM is not updated, how can I check if the inputs are invalid in order to make the test case fail?

Comment: @EmmaE : I do not have any idea about server side validation using Selenium. I am afraid to tell you that you will have to go with client side validation using selenium.

Comment: Try checking for the pre submitted value by using the element's properties (accessed via getAttribute()). e.g. using the input search box on this page:


    webElement.getAttribute("value")

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing explicit wait in Your code. What that mean, is that You wait for some condition to be set, here is example how to manage this:

But my suggestion is that You assert if there are some error messages (labels, span, or whatever that appears saying something is wrong with email or pass)

So here is how I would do it:

```
        WebDriver driver;

        @DataProvider(name= "testdata")
        public static Object[][] loginData(){
            return new Object[][]{{"username1", "123"}, {"username2", "4211"}};
        }

        @BeforeTest
        public void configure(){
          driver = new WebDriver();
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //this is wait which will wait until driver throws exception (that is not found eg."NoSuchElementException")
        }

        @Test(dataProvider = "testdata")
        public void testmethod(String uname, String password){

             WebElement usernameTextbox = driver.findElement(By.id("usernameID"));
                 usernameTextbox.sendKeys(uname);

       WebElement passwordTextbox = driver.findElement(By.id("passwordID"));
                 passwordTextbox.sendKeys(password); //here is where You've sent wrong param


// if You know You will get error label or something use this
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); //wait for max 10 sec, and wait for error element defined bellow
       WebElement errorElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions. presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("someErrorElementId")));  //(or ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(..)), see what better suites You

// If You're expecting error than use this assert
        Assert.assertTrue(errorElement.isDisplayed(),"There should be error message!")

// but If You're expecting that there should not be any error than use this assert
        Assert.assertFalse(errorElement.isDisplayed(),"There shouldn't be no error messages!")
    }
```

tweak this code, but basicaly this is the logic.

Answer (score 0):

So to try to answer the original question your code could look like below:
 1. Using the getAttribute("value")
 2. Building the assertion - you don't need to wrap the condition in an if as the contains() function will return true or false for you:

```
WebDriver driver;

@DataProvider(name= "testdata")
public static Object[][] loginData(){
    return new Object[][]{{"username1", "123"}, {"username2", "4211"}};
}

@BeforeTest
public void configure(){
    ....
}

@Test(dataProvider = "testdata")
public void testmethod(String uname, String password){
    WebElement usernameTextbox = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
        usernameTextbox.sendKeys(uname);

    WebElement passwordTextbox = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
        passwordTextbox.sendKeys(uname);

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);

    Assert.assertTrue(usernameTextbox.getAttribute("value").contains("[a-zA-Z0-9]+") &&  passwordTextbox.getAttribute("value").contains("[0-9]+"));
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

As per your question just after invoking `sendKeys()` you want to do some assertions.

At this point it is worth to mention that when you invoke `sendKeys()` on a `<input>` node/tag/field the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) is not immediately updated with the *value* / *characters* which you have just entered in majority of the cases (of-coarse there are exceptional cases). Moving forward when you invoke `click()` or `submit()`on a `<button>` or similar `<input>` element, the associated [**`onclick`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) event of this `<input>` element updates the *HTML DOM* and the *value* / *characters* previously sent through `sendKeys()` are adjusted within the *HTML DOM*.

Unless the *value* / *characters* are not accommodated within the [**DOM Tree**](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) *Selenium* won't be able to interact with them.

As per your code block, you have populated the `passwordTextbox` field with the `String` value of `uname` as follows :

```
passwordTextbox.sendKeys(uname);
```

This *value* / *characterset* is still volatile and editable (can be overwritten/cleared/deleted) as follows :

```
passwordTextbox.clear();
passwordTextbox.sendKeys("Emma E");
```

Essentially, `Assert` methods can be invoked on **text** those are part of the *HTML DOM*. As an example you can use the following `Assert` for a *Page Heading*, *Table Heading*, etc :

```
Assert.assertTrue(if(pageHeaderElement.contains("[a-zA-Z0-9]+") &&  tableHeaderElement.contains("[0-9]+") == true));
```

Comment: I use webElement.getAttribute("value") to extract the current text value of an input element before it has been submitted, as per answer above.

Comment: @elworthy Incase the desired _webElement_ contains a default value which is reflected within the _HTML DOM_ then you may be able to use `getAttribute("value")` to retrieve the text. Else you won't be able to do so.